# How can i handle static asset file in Vite?

Tags: typescript, vite

i have svg file in `"public/img/"` directory.
when i import this img file as `import imgUrl from './img/googlenews.svg';` it doesn't work.

This is the file path where I wrote the `import` rule *(not sure if this is an important detail)* `"src/resources/articles.ts"`

and here my `vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),
      '~bootstrap': resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: './index.html'
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFileNames: 'js/[name].js',
        //assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`,
        assetFileNames: ({name}) => {
          if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/.test(name ?? '')){
              return 'img/[name][extname]';
          }
          
          if (/\.css$/.test(name ?? '')) {
              return 'css/[name][extname]';   
          }
 
          // default value
          // ref: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputassetfilenames
          return 'img/[name][extname]';
        },
      }
    },
  },
});
```

and here Vite official [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets):

*Importing a static asset will return the resolved public URL when it is served:*

```
import imgUrl from './img.png'
document.getElementById('hero-img').src = imgUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

The `public` folder is a special folder in Vite that can't be accessed from an `import` statement, but only from the client. To import your image, place it in another directory (e.g. `/assets`), and then import it as you would any other file:

```js
import imgURL from '/assets/img.png';
```